# Picard's Theorem - Lipschitz Condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Consider $y'=3y^{2/3},y(0)=0$  and let $R$ be the rectangle $|x|\leq1,|y|\leq1.$ Here $f(x,y)=3y^{2/3}$ is plainly continuous on $R$.

Also $y_1(x)=x^3$ and $y_2(x)=0$ are two different solutions valid for all $x$ thus the equation is not unique.

The non uniqueness lies in the fact that $f(x,y)$ does not satisfy a Lipschitz condition on the rectangle $R$, since the difference quotient

$\frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y=0}=\frac{3y^{2/3}}{y}=\frac{3}{y^{1/3}}$ (*)

is unbounded in every neighborhood of the origin.

This is the explanation in my textbook but I have some questions about it and would appreciate some clarification.

1) How did they obtain the two solutions, $y_1(x), y_2(x)$?

2) How do you know which values to plug into equation (*)  and how does this help you see uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

$y'=3y^{2/3},y(0)=0$ can be solved separating variables

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=3y^{2/3}\rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{3y^{2/3}}=dx$

Integrating both sides $y^\frac13=x+c\rightarrow y=x^3$

$c=0$ for the initial condition

The solution $y=0$ is obvious: $0=3\cdot 0^\frac23$